# C# - Image to Int[] - Wrong number of elements

Tags: c#

I want to convert a bitmap image to Int array, so that I can calculate the sum of all elements in that array and do other math calculations.

Using Aforge.NET I have extracted green channel and acquired a cropped version of the image. The dimensions of the cropped image says: 1989 x 115 = 228735 pixels. After using Lockbits and Marshal.Copy for converting it into int array, the dimension of the array is 229080; which is more than its supposed to be; below is my code, do advise me on the mistake I am doing.

```
// create filter
ExtractBiggestBlob BBB = new ExtractBiggestBlob();
// apply the filter
Bitmap biggestBlobsImage = BBB.Apply(ChannelImage); // works perfect; set all pictureBox to Zoom size
pictureBox1.Image = biggestBlobsImage; // pictureBox1 - GreenChannelCroppedImage
Console.WriteLine(biggestBlobsImage.Width);
Console.WriteLine(biggestBlobsImage.Height);
// Next step - Display rotation corrected image in pictureBox3
// Convert the Bitmap biggestBlobsImage to Int array;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, biggestBlobsImage.Width, biggestBlobsImage.Height);
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
  biggestBlobsImage.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, biggestBlobsImage.PixelFormat);

IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * biggestBlobsImage.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

// Copy the RGB values into the array.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

// do something with the array
Console.WriteLine(rgbValues.Length);
Console.WriteLine(rgbValues.Rank);

// Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

biggestBlobsImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Comment: Assuming you've read explanations of properties you are using to compute the size it is unclear why you expect odd number of bytes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are correctly copying Stride by Height, not Width by Height. You have to use Stride because when you have a 24bit per pixel which needs 3 bytes for each pixel, then on a 32bit memory you can have few bytes at end of each row not used. 
for example if you have 1pixel by 1 pixel image, while you need only 24bits, but you take 32 bits because you have to take whole words (32 bit in a 32bit system, or 64 on a 64bit memory system)

Comment: Thank you n00b for explaining to a noob :)